# Are the Panasonic Leica DG Summilux 25mm/F1.4 ASPH models H-X025 and the H-X025E the same lens?

Tags: lens, panasonic

I just ordered a lens from a website that said H-X025E, but the box that has arrived says H-X025. Are they the same, or have I been delivered an older model?

After looking around, most reviews just refer to the lens as the H-X025.

However, the [official website](http://panasonic.com.au/Products/Lumix+digital+cameras/Accessories/Micro+43rds+interchangeable+lenses/H-X025E/Overview) refers to the lens as H-X025E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panasonic replied to me:

> Thank you for taking the time to contact Panasonic with your enquiry.
>
> H-X025 and the H-X205E are the same model, the prefix on the end is
>   for different countries where the unit is sold. The Australian model
>   is the H-X205E.

Answer (score 6):

The *E* is a regional suffix. You point to the Australian Panasonic site but on the [Canadian one](https://panasonic.ca/english/audiovideo/camerascamcorders/lenses/lenses.asp) for example, there is no version with the *E*. Quite commonly the *E* letter is for Europe and the product is almost always identical except that it may have been certified by a different set of standards.

Comment: Thank-you, it was good to have your reply as Panasonic took 8 days to reply to my email and I wanted to open the box! (upvoted)